# Export <div>...</div> as a html document with all resource (Like online webpage Template builder )

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm currently building a online webpage creator with drag & drop feature using js, jQuery, Ajax ,jsp and html. I looking for code to publish the template after completing the bage by drag & drop the contents.

The template built with in a

```
<div>..</div>
```

tag itself. I have to create it as a separate html document with demo page.
the resources(css & js) of the the DIV tags also should be export.i have to store the new htmldocument in server side.

Can any one suggest me the way to achieve as i said & suggest me if u know any tutorials.

Comment: If you wish to include external resources from links - parse HTML for CSS and JS links (hard). If just get all contents from `<div></div>` than `$('div').html()`

Comment: Can u give example for export <div></div> into new html document  using $('div').html()  and i have to store the new html in server side.

Answer (score 0):

You will need JS and PHP to store HTML content to file on server.

First of all get wrapper content using `.html()`. I suggest transferring all inner HTML to some template (`$('#file-wrapper html body').html($('#other-content-div').html());`:

```
<script id="file-wrapper" type="template">
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>Hello World!</body>
    </html>
</script>

var fileContent = $('#myWrapper').html();
```

Now send that content to server:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'save.php',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {fileContent: fileContent},
    dataType: 'json'
    success: function (json) {
        if (json.status) {
            // saved
        } else {
            // not saved
        }
    }
});
```

On PHP side check if you received any content and just save it to file using [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php):

```
if (!empty($_POST['fileContent'])) {
    $filePath = __DIR__.'/custom-html-'.date('Y-m-d').'-'.rand(0, 9999).'.html';

    file_put_contents($filePath, $_POST['fileContent']);

    echo json_encode(array('status' => true, 'message' => 'File saved'));
} else {
    echo json_encode(array('status' => false, 'message' => 'No data received'));
}
```